# randomly arrange elements in ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of objects which form a mathematical set. So I want to display them in an ellipse like this:

[image: set with 5 objects]

If I then add a new object, the ellipse should grow and the 6th element should be placed inside the ellipse.

I thought I could solve this problem with an iteration. At first place `object1` and the **Name of set** and draw the ellipse. Secondly add `object2` and let the ellipse grow, and so on.
But I already struggled to find a proper solution for the arrangement of the first step, not to mention the growth of the ellipse in the second step. My problem with the first step is, that the ellipse should be smaller when **Name of set** and `object1` have a small string representation. And the ellipse should be bigger, if **Name of set** and `object1` have a longer string representation.

Or did I get somewhere on the wrong track? Maybe there is already a (framework?) solution for this problem, which I overlook.

Comment: So that we're all thinking in the same direction, can you post a few details about your current implementation? Are you working with a view/codebehind pattern? MVVM? Any frameworks (MVVM Light/Caliburn/etc.)?

Comment: I am working with a slightly adopted MVP. Since its wpf it is also xaml with codebehind. No other frameworks than .NET used. But I don't see, what you need these infos for?!?

Comment: An MVVM implementation of this problem differs substantially from a view/codebehind implementation. You'll get very different code solutions posted for each. Can you post a sample of how you add and remove objects to the ellipse?

Comment: I want a solution of **How to arrange objects and a Name in an ellipse**... I think, that the answer looks like an idea of an algorithm, which everyone can than adopt for MVVM or MVP. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I've seen some good representation which cope with this kind of thing by modeling forces between the elements. then you can just plop them all in and let physics sort it out  ie http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500

Answer (score 0):

Create an integer property called `MyCount`.
Create integer constants OriginalWidth and OriginalHeight.
Create integer variables ScaledWidth and ScaledHeight.

When your set is created add `mySet.Name.Count()` to `MyCount`.

When you add an object, add `myObject.SomeProperty.ToString().Count()` to `MyCount`.

When you remove an object, subtract `myObject.SomeProperty.ToString().Count()` from `MyCount`.

When MyCount is changed, recalculate `ScaledWidth` and `ScaledHeight` - something like `ScaledWidth = OriginalWidth * (MyCount * [insert number here])`

In order to keep your ellipse in the correct perspective your Ellipse's Height and Width will be based on constant values multiplied by a scaling factor, which is `MyCount`. You need 4 integer values: `OriginalWidth`, `OriginalHeight`, `ScaledWidth` and `ScaledHeight`. `OriginalWidth` and `OriginalHeight` are integer constants defining the minimum width and height of your Ellipse. `ScaledWidth` and `ScaledHeight` are integer variables which your Ellipse's Height and Width properties are bound to.

Every time a new object is added or removed to/from your set the number of characters in its `SomeProperty` is added to `MyCount`. Every time `MyCount` changes it triggers the recalculation of `ScaledWidth` and `ScaledHeight`. Binding your Ellipse's Width and Height properties to `ScaledWidth` and `ScaledHeight`, and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on these properties, should scale your Ellipse accordingly.

UPDATE

The algorithm posted here: http://programming.nullanswer.com/forum/11925 would appear to address placing your child elements within your parent ellipse. I've substituted ellipse for square/circle where appropriate:

Pick a random point inside the [parent ellipse] & instance a [very low Width/Height ellipse] at that point.
Grow the radius of that [ellipse] till it satisfies these criteria:

- does not overlap any of the other chosen [ellipses].
- does not extend outside the [parent ellipse].

Choose the [ellipse] if it satisfies these criteria.

Comment: Okay. So far for the scaling of the ellipse. Do you also have a good advise for the random arrangement of the objects inside the ellipse?